# sub query solution for join

Tags: php, mysql, join

i have following query which gives me error when i run it,

```
SELECT events.id AS id, SUM(tickets_sold.quantity)
FROM (`events`)
JOIN `category` AS cat ON `events`.`category_id` = `cat`.`id` 
JOIN `category` AS sub_cat ON `events`.`subCategoryID` = `sub_cat`.`id` 
JOIN `events_custom_dates` AS events_date ON `events_date`.`event_id` = `events`.`id`
JOIN `my_promos` ON `events`.id = `my_promos`.`event_id`
LEFT JOIN `mycalendar` ON `mycalendar`.`event_id` = `my_promos`.`event_id` 
LEFT JOIN `promo_events_stats` ON `promo_events_stats`.`id` = `events`.`id` 

JOIN `tickets_sold` ON  `my_promos`.`link_code` = `tickets_sold`.`code` 
WHERE `my_promos`.`user_id` = '532' AND DATE(my_promos.date) >= '2013-11-01' AND DATE(my_promos.date) <= '2014-01-22' 
GROUP BY my_promos.event_id
```

it gives me

```
id   sum(tickets.sold)
some id    `2`
some id    `4`
some id   `14`
```

but it should give

```
some id    `2`
some id    `4`
some id    `7`
```

when i remove the following line from the above query it gives me right data

```
JOIN `events_custom_dates` AS events_date ON `events_date`.`event_id` = `events`.`id`
```

so please tell me what should i do now.. event_id is the only foreign key against which i can makes its join with events table.

Comment: Your query doesn't seem to use `event_dates` apart from the join.  Just remove it from the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no i cant remove it because there are so many other things which are relying on this event_dates join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your require solution

```
SELECT events.id AS id,A.sold_tickets
FROM (`events`)
JOIN `category` AS cat ON `events`.`category_id` = `cat`.`id` 
JOIN `category` AS sub_cat ON `events`.`subCategoryID` = `sub_cat`.`id` 
JOIN `events_custom_dates` AS events_date ON `events_date`.`event_id` = `events`.`id`
JOIN `my_promos` ON `events`.id = `my_promos`.`event_id`
LEFT JOIN `mycalendar` ON `mycalendar`.`event_id` = `my_promos`.`event_id` 
LEFT JOIN `promo_events_stats` ON `promo_events_stats`.`id` = `events`.`id` 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT my_promos.event_id, SUM(tickets_sold.quantity) AS sold_tickets FROM my_promos
JOIN tickets_sold ON tickets_sold.code = my_promos.link_code
WHERE my_promos.user_id = '532' AND DATE(my_promos.date) >= '2013-11-01' AND DATE(my_promos.date) <= '2014-01-22' 
GROUP BY my_promos.event_id) A ON A.event_id = events.id

WHERE `my_promos`.`user_id` = '532' AND DATE(my_promos.date) >= '2013-11-01' AND DATE(my_promos.date) <= '2014-01-22' 
GROUP BY my_promos.event_id
```

Comment: shazada lagyan wah @saadk

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
select * 
from events
join events_custom_dates as events_date on events_date.event_id = events.id;
```

give the result you're expecting?  I expect there could be a problem with the schema, but without being able to see it, that's a bit of a stab in the dark.

Comment: no i does not give the answer i expect. but if i remove it, then it gives me the right answer, but i cant remove it too.. there are other things to,o which lying on it.

Comment: You'll need to fix your schema if you're not getting the join you're expecting.